# Drupal 7, how to set up "Forum" module in my own theme

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I've created my own theme in Drupal 7, and I would like to use the core module "Forum" in my website. Here is what I have done so far:

1. Enabled "Forum" module in Modules
2. Created a region called "forum" in .info file
3. Assigned blocks "Active forum topics" and "New forum topics" to region "forum"
4. Created a container and forum under /admin/structure/forum
5. Created a page template "page--page-forum.tpl.php", in that template I render "forum" region
6. And my page where the "forum" is rendered shows "Active forum topics" and "Forum", 2 lines, text only, nothing else.

From my observation the page doesn't really hooks the module templates, such as "forums.tpl.php", "forum-list.tpl.php", "forum-topic-list.tpl.php", etc, which are stored in /modules/forum

So my question is how can I implement the "forum" module in my own theme?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to copy the "forums.tpl.php" file and other tpl files from their location in the modules directory to your custom theme directory in sites/all/themes/yourcustomtheme/templates

More details can be found here:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22206/advanced-forum-how-to-change-the-html-without-modifying-the-core